# Присвоить переменную

Tags: php, mysql, sql

мне нужно вот этому `<input id="4"type="text" name="numstat">`   присвоить значение вот этого `$PoleCauseID`

т.е. что бы когда открывалась страница, в numstat было значение PoleCauseID 
код ниже $PoleCauseID берет данные с БД

```
<form method="POST"  action="">
          <input id="4"type="text" name="numstat" value="$PoleCauseID">
          <input id="5" type="submit" name="cause" value="1Вызвать">
          <input id="6" type="submit" name="served" value="Обслжуен"/>
      </form>
    <?php // Вызвать
          $host = "localhost";
          $username = "root";
          $password = "";
          $dbname = "ironbank";
          if (isset($_POST['cause']))
             {  $PoleCauseID;
                $PoleCauseNumber;
                $connect = mysqli_connect ($host, $username, $password, $dbname); // подключение к базе
                          mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");
                $connect->set_charset('utf8');
                $chek_query = " SELECT * FROM Business "; // Подключение к таблице
                $db = mysqli_query ($connect, $chek_query) or die("Ошибка" .mysqli_error($connect)); 





                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $db))  // Присвоение ID
                    {
                           $PoleID = $row['ID'];
                           $PoleNumber = $row['Number'];
                           $PoleName = $row['name'];
                           $PoleStatus = $row['Status'];
                           $PoleCod =$row['cod'];
                           $PoleDate = $row['date'];
                           $PoleTime = $row['time'];    
                     if ($PoleCod == 1)  
                        {               
                          $PoleCauseID =  $PoleID + 1;
                          $PoleCauseNumber = $PoleNumber + 1;                         
                        }    
                    }   

                     echo " ID = $PoleCauseID, Number = $PoleCauseNumber |";


             }

      ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала выполняете скрипт, потом уже выводите разметку, в которую и вставляете переменную через `echo`

```
<?php // Вызвать
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ironbank";
if (isset($_POST['cause']))
 {  $PoleCauseID;
  $PoleCauseNumber;
                $connect = mysqli_connect ($host, $username, $password, $dbname); // подключение к базе
                mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");
                $connect->set_charset('utf8');
                $chek_query = " SELECT * FROM Business "; // Подключение к таблице
                $db = mysqli_query ($connect, $chek_query) or die("Ошибка" .mysqli_error($connect)); 





                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $db))  // Присвоение ID
                {
                 $PoleID = $row['ID'];
                 $PoleNumber = $row['Number'];
                 $PoleName = $row['name'];
                 $PoleStatus = $row['Status'];
                 $PoleCod =$row['cod'];
                 $PoleDate = $row['date'];
                 $PoleTime = $row['time'];    
                 if ($PoleCod == 1)  
                 {               
                  $PoleCauseID =  $PoleID + 1;
                  $PoleCauseNumber = $PoleNumber + 1;                         
                }    
              }   

              echo " ID = $PoleCauseID, Number = $PoleCauseNumber |";


            }

            ?>

            <form method="POST"  action="">
              <input id="4"type="text" name="numstat" value="<?php echo $PoleCauseID; ?>">
              <input id="5" type="submit" name="cause" value="1Вызвать">
              <input id="6" type="submit" name="served" value="Обслжуен"/>
            </form>
```